# Number of ways to remove nodes from a graph with certain restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle, dynamic-programming

This question is from [ZIO $2010$](https://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2010/zio2010/zio2010-qpaper.pdf). I thought of using a bottom up approach, calculating the possible subsets from the leaves, and then making my way up. I'm not to sure why it isn't working. The question  is:

Sales have slumped at the Zionoi noodle factory and the management may need to
terminate the contracts of some employees. Every employee has one immediate boss.
The seniormost person in the company is the president, who has no boss. For legal reasons, if an employee’s contract is not terminated, then his or her boss’s contract cannot be terminated either. For how many different sets of employees can the management legally terminate contracts? Note that one possibility that has to be counted explicitly is that no employees’ contracts are terminated (that is, the set of employees whose contract is terminated is the empty set).

For example, suppose there are four employees, organised as follows. Each arrow points
from an employee to his or her boss.

[image: Image 1]

Here, there are $7$ different ways to terminate contracts for a set of employees, as follows:

$\Bigg[\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{\}, \{4\}, \{2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{2, 4\}, \{2, 3, 4\}\Bigg]$

In each of the following cases, compute the number of different sets of employees whose
contracts can be legally terminated by the management.

[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 4]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: It might prove useful to count the number of invalid sets of dismissals instead. Then subtract that result from $2^n$, where $n$ is the total number of employees.

Comment: It's still to big! I know the answer, which is 691 if it's of any help. 2^13 on the other hand is 8192!

Comment: You could try to determine how many ways there are to eliminate $k, k=0,1,2,\dots$ employees, but it looks fairly tedious.

Comment: exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423924/removing-nodes-from-graphs-such-that-one-is-dependent-on-other-zio-2010-p1/3423989#3423989 -- @AdityaDutt - pls try to invest at least a bit of effort searching next time.  :)

Comment: @antkam I am sorry. The question was posted as an image and hence searching for it did not work. The question that showed up was this one.

Comment: @AdityaDutt - ah, I see.  Sigh, it's really bad when people post the question as an image, but I agree it's not your fault in this case.  Peace!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(i)$ be the number of admissible terminations for the subtree rooted at node $i$. By conditioning on whether employee $i$ is terminated or not, we have $f(i)=1+\prod_j f(j)$, where the product is over employees $j$ that report to $i$. The leaf nodes have $f(i)=2$. Now work your way up the tree to eventually compute the desired value $f(1)$.