# Removing nodes from graphs such that one is dependent on other - ZIO $2010$, P$1$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, puzzle, dynamic-programming

[image]
[image]

Greetings Community! The above problem you see is a combinatorics problem I could not solve. :( This problem is from ZIO $2010$, P$1$.

> Here is what I did: Observe that every graph can be divided into "sub-groups" which may help in solving. We first remove the empty set. Then the singleton set. Consider the bigger but smaller than the sub-parts example: [image: sub-part]
>   The singleton sets are $\{4,5,6\}$ which are at the least position in the graph.
>   The dual sets are $\{2,4\}, \{3,5\}, \{3,6\}$, the bottom - two portions in the graph. The triplet sets are $\{2,4,5\}, \{4,5,6\}$ which we may manually count but for the bigger graphs in the sub-part, this may prove to be difficult and this is where I am stuck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here, is the "inversion" of the boss statement to the following :

> If an employee's boss is sacked, he is sacked as well.

From which we get :

> If a person is sacked, all his employees are sacked.

Therefore , we get the following : every "valid set of sackings" corresponds to a unique list of bosses who were sacked. And none  of these bosses are bosses to any of the others.

For example, consider the example given in the question. The sacking $\{1,2,3,4\}$  corresponds to the sacking of boss $\{1\}$. The sacking $\{2,3,4\}$ corresponds to the  list $\{2,3\}$ since $4$ below $3$ will also be sacked. Note that $\{2,3\}$ are not bosses of each other.

---

Why do we get the number $7$ now? Let us think.

The tree has root $1$, with two subtrees, one is $2$ and the other is $3 \to 4$.

Now, I claim the following : every valid sacking is of two types, one consisting of all being sacked, and the other being a union of valid sackings over all subtrees(may be empty).

This is obvious : indeed, given a valid sacking, look at the unique boss list, and these bosses are sitting in different subtrees of the original tree, so we get a sacking from each subtree by looking at the bosses in each of the subtrees.

Similarly, given valid sackings over all subtrees, you get by taking their union, a valid sacking, which is easy to check.

Let us take examples from the last given question to clarify what I mean, since I intend to use a complicated scenario here.

Let's take $(b)$. Consider the given sackings :

- The sacking $\{5,8,9,7,14\}$ corresponds to the unique boss list : $\{5,7\}$. Note that $\{5,8,9\}$ is a valid sacking of the subtree under $2$, and $\{7,14\}$ is a valid sacking of the subtree under $3$. Conversely, given these sackings, their union gives the full sack list.
- The sacking $\{4,8,11,13,16\}$ comes from the unique list $\{4,8,11,13\}$, and one sees that $\{4,8\}$ is a valid sacking of the subtree under $2$, similarly $\{11,13,16\}$ is a valid sacking of the subtree under $3$.
- In the original example (the $1,2,3,4$ one) the sacking corresponding to $\{3,4\}$ has unique boss list $\{3\}$ , and $\{\}$(nobody sacked : I suspect bribery here!) is a valid sacking under $2$ while $\{3,4\}$ is a valid sacking under $3$.

Thus, we can *recursively* count the number of valid sackings.

When we hit a tree, we either sack everybody, or choose a valid sacking from each  child and put them together. Thus, we get :$$\textrm{No. of valid sackings} = 1 + \prod_{\textrm{child subtrees}} \textrm{no. of valid sackings of this child subtree}
$$

Note : $\prod$ stands for product, we are choosing each subtree sacking independently so we take the product.

We need the base case as well : in a singleton tree, you either sack all or sack none, so that gives the number as $2$.

Finally, let us calculate using this formula, the answer for the original example.

---

No of sackings of $\{1,2,3,4\} = 1 + $ no of sackings of $\{2\} \times $ no of sackings of $\{3,4\}$.

No of sackings of $\{2\} = 2$ from base case.

No of sackings of $\{3,4\} = 1 + $ no of sackings of $\{4\}$ (there's only one subtree) $=1+2 = 3$.

So finally we get $1 + 2 \times 3 = 7$!

We need to do this procedure for the other trees. Let us do it for $(a)$, I leave you to see it for the others.

---

For $(a)$ : Let us use notation, with $N(t)$ the number of valid sackings for the subtree under $t$. Naturally we want to find $N(1)$.

Then : $N(1) = 1 + N(2)N(3)N(4)$. We compute each one separately below, from easiest to hardest.

---

$N(2) = 1 + N(5) = 1+2 = 3$.

---

$N(4) = 1 + N(8)N(9) = 1 + 2 \times 2 = 5$.

---

$N(3) = 1 + N(6)N(7)$. See $N(6) = 5$ yourself, and $N(7) = 1 + N(12)N(13)N(14) = 1 + 2  \times 2 \times 2 = 9$. So we get $N(3) = 46$.

---

Combining, $N(1) = 1 + 3 \times 5 \times 46 = 691$. So there are $691$ sackings possible here.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It is really easy to understand and a pretty concise one indeed!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Hey @TeresaLisbon do you mind explaining how you though of using recursion here, I had the same idea but it didn't lead to recursion.

Comment: @ShlokJain That one must use recursion, follows from the inversion statement I made at the beginning of my answer. The point is, the property of the tree that dictates what you can remove from it, basically comes down to each of its subtrees, and that immediately indicates recursion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You need a recurrence.

Consider a sub-tree, rooted at node $x$.

Let $f(x) =$ the number of ways to fire people in this sub-tree (including not firing anyone).

Suppose $x$ has $k$ children.

- If $k=0$, i.e. $x$ is a leaf, then there are two ways to fire people involving this subtree, i.e. $\{\}$ and $\{x\}$.
- If $k=1$, let the child of $x$ be called $y$.  Can you write $f(x)$ in terms of $f(y)$?
- If $k=2$, let the children by $y_1, y_2$.  Can you write $f(x)$ in terms of $f(y_1), f(y_2)$?
- For general $k$, can you write $f(x)$ in terms of $f(y_1), \dots, f(y_k)$?

Once you have the recurrence, test it on the sample $4$-node tree, starting from the leaves and going up the tree - and remember that $f(\text{leaf}) = 2$ (not $1$).  If you get the answer $7$ after you arrive at the root node, chances are your recurrence is correct.