# A sequence with dominoes

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

My friend ran into this problem years ago. He asked for my help, but I couldn't solve it either. The setting is as follows.

Dominoes are placed in a triangular formation. Something like this...

```
 ㅁ
ㅁㅁ  (n=2)
```

Rules: 1. If a domino is hit, it may fall or it may not. 2. If a domino is not hit, it does not fall.

Problem: $D_n$ is the number of scenarioes possible for a given $n$. Find the explicit formula of $D_n$.

Example: For n=2, The domino on the top may or may not fall. If it does not fall, the two dominoes under it do not fall. If it does, the two dominoes may or may not fall. Therefore $D_2=5$.

Clarification: The rule is: the top domino can fall; for any non-top domino, it can fall only if at least one domino above it falls.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the rule.  What does it mean to "hit" a domino?  Maybe if you explain the example of $D_3 = 18$ it would make more sense.  My original interpretation is that if a domino is not falling then the entire "triangle" under it cannot be falling, but in this interpretation, if my counting is correct, I only get $D_3 = 14$ (which is a Catalan number).

Comment: @antkam If any of the two dominoes above a given domino falls, the domino can fall. If the domino is on the edge of the triangle, having only one domino above it, it can fall if that domino falls. I hope this is clear enough. If it isn't please tell me how to add pictures. This is the best I can explain in text.

Comment: OK so the rule is: the top domino can fall; for any non-top domino, it can fall only if at least one domino on top is falling.  right?  That does make $D_3 = 18$.  I was taken by surprise since that's not how real dominoes behave.  :)

Comment: For future reference the sequence begins with $$2, 5, 18, 97, 802, 10565, 228850,\dots$$for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ which I calculated by a brute force numerical method. This sequence does not appear to be in the OEIS.

Comment: @antkam hope you're doing well :) I added your last comment to the (very vague) post

Comment: My attempt at explaining the setup: The view is looking down on a bunch of domino tiles standing up in a big triangle. We then try to flick the first domino, and (if it falls) it then topples into the next row, but maybe at some angle, so it might only hit one of its descendants. Each domino that gets knocked over then also may knock over one (or both) of its immediate children, and the process continues.

Comment: The next value is 8289217.

Comment: I am not sure if this is appropriate, but @PeterForeman how did you calculate it? Did you go through all $2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ configurations and checked the requirements? If so, that $O(n^22^{n^2})$ (All the $n^2$ should be triangular number to be exact$).

Comment: @GarethMa At the moment, you can do it in "just" exponential time, see [my second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614032/318073) and [@Bartek's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3616657/318073).

Comment: Thank you, this is really interesting. O(4^n) is much better than O(n^2*2^(n^2)) haha.

Comment: It might prove fruitful to start with the $2^n$ possible 'lights on' for the bottom row, and work out which binomial paths can lead to this situation.

Comment: @PeterForeman, this is now on OEIS as [A333837](https://oeis.org/A333837).

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** I found a recurrence in my alternative approach answer, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614032/318073).

---

**TL;DR**

I've reduced the problem to calculating "domino coefficients".

But it appears these coefficients cannot be easily calculated, and that's where my answer stops.

---

**Reducing the problem to "domino coefficients"**

If $d_n$ is the number of scenarios with at least one fallen domino in the $n$*th* row, then

$$D_n=D_{n-1}+d_n$$

We define $D_0=1,d_1=1$. This gives $D_1=1+1=2$ as expected.

We say a domino is "activated" (can fall) if and only if a domino above it has fallen.

> $\alpha_n(k)$ is the number of ways to have exactly $k$ "activated" dominoes in the $n$*th* row.

Now to calculate $d_n,n\ge2$ we have the expression:

$$d_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_n(k) \cdot (2^k-1)$$

Because every "activated" domino is either fallen or not, giving $2^k$ states, and we subtract $1$ for the case when they are all not fallen because that's the definition of $d_n$.

If a domino falls, it activates the two dominoes below it. This implies that $\alpha_n(1)=0$ because we never have exactly one activated domino. Hence we define $\alpha$ for $2\le k\le n$.

> The problem is now calculating the "domino coefficients" $\alpha_n(k)$.

By brute force I've found the triangle that gives $\alpha_n(k)$'s  for $2\le k\le 7$ is:

$$\begin{array}{}
&&&&&& 1 \\
&&&&& 2 && 1 \\
&&&& 7 && 4 && 2 \\
&&& 34 && 21 && 18 && 6 \\
&& 233 && 152 && 184 && 104 && 32 \\
& 2370 && 1609 && 2552 && 1888 && 1056 && 288 \\
 .&& .&& .&& .&& .&& .&& .\\
\end{array}$$

Reading rows $n=2,3,4,5,6,7$ and plugging the coefficients into the recursion:

$$D_n=D_{n-1}+\sum_{k=2}^n \alpha_n(k) \cdot (2^k-1)$$

Gives $D_n=5,18,97,802,10565,228850$ as expected. (Where $D_1=2$.)

---

**Solving the domino coefficients?**

For $k=2$, to activate exactly two dominoes in $(n)$*th* row, exactly one domino must fall in $(n-1)$*th* row. This gives the recursion for the first coefficient:

$$\alpha_n(2)=\sum_{r=2}^{n-1}\alpha_{n-1}(r)\cdot r $$

But for $k\ge 3$, I do not see an obvious recursion.

The number of ways activated dominoes in the $(n-1)$*th* row can fall now depends on the "islands" (consecutive runs of activated dominoes) and "gaps" (consecutive runs of non-activated dominoes). To write this as an expression,

Let $S(n-1,r)$ be the set of all $(n-1)$*th* row sequences of dominoes where exactly $r$ dominoes are activated. Then we have to sum over all $s\in S(n-1,r)$:

$$
\alpha_n(k)=\sum_{r=2}^{n-1}\sum_{s\in S(n-1,r)}f_k(s)
$$

Where $f_k(s)$ returns a value depending on the size of each "island" $I\in s$ and depending on the value of the target number of activations $k$ in the $n$*th* row.

Collecting all $s$ sequences and evaluating $f_k(s)$ function on them is a problem now.

Notice that the number of elements of $S(n-1,r)$ is precisely $\alpha_{n-1}(r)$.

If $k=2$, we simply have $f_2(s)=r$ for all $s$, which gives the recursion $\alpha_{n}(2)$ from above.

If $k=3$, we have $f_3(s)=(r-1)$ if the $s$ contains exactly one island $I$ of length $r$. Otherwise, we need to observe individual islands, to get:

$$f_3(s)=\sum_{I\in s}(\mathcal L(I)-1)$$

where $\mathcal L(I)$ is the length of the island $I\in s$. This is true because to have $k=3$ activated dominoes in the $(n)$*th* row, we need to have exactly two connected dominoes in the $(n-1)$*th* row.

For $k\ge 4$, the $f_k(s)$ is not anymore "as simple" as summing lengths of islands.

For $k=3$ we counted ways:

- to activate "single $2$-long partitions" of the islands

For $k=4$ we need to count ways:

- to activate "single $3$-long partitions" of the islands
- to activate "two $1$-long partitions" separated with gap of at least one

And so on, for larger $k$ we have more ways to "partition the activations" of islands.

> I do not see how to simplify this into a "closed form (recursion) expression ".

Hence my answer stops here.

Comment: Nice approach. Regarding $\alpha_n(k)$, it is a gaps & islands problem, and I think there is no closed form, and the recursive function should also make decision, i.e. how many islands (neighbouring activated dominoes) and of what size are generated by the previous activated dominoes, because for one island the formula is different than for separate islands together due to overlapping.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó It appears something like that is the case. The recursion for $k\ge 4$ coefficients is not straightforward because it depends whether or not the sequence of activated dominoes is connected (a single island?) or not (multiple islands of varying sizes?), which is I think what you meant by "for one island the formula is different than for separate islands together due to overlapping"? - Also, is there any mathematical literature or reference for the "gaps & islands" problem? Google searches always lead me to "gaps & islands problem in SQL" context.

Comment: You see it right, and yes, I borrowed the "gaps & islands" expression from data-querying (SQL) related to similar problem. I don't know the math-related expression. I think, there is none, as this can not be solved with a formula/function, but rather with an algorithm,  that returns multiple information, i.e. how many islands there are and of what sizes. This is why I think there is no formula for the whole problem either, I just don't know how it could be proved.

Comment: Maybe the gaps & islands problem needs to be addressed with graph theory. The whole problem could be, as we can ask "how many paths lead to a certain point in the specified graph from a given starting point"? But I don't have deep knowledge of graph theory.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I found we can encode the sequence into a ["domino matrix"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614032/318073), which appears to hide a [fractal structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nEeY.png).

Comment: The only possible connection I found to something in the OEIS is that the right-hand edge $a_n(n)$ data you provided matches [A088437](http://oeis.org/A088437); does $a_8(8) = 4608$?

Comment: @BrianHopkins  It is $a_8(8)=4448$ which is not in OEIS. Namely, next row is:
$$(k=2,\dots,8),a_8(k)=37567,26236,51946,45288,35296,17504,4448$$ 
Notice that $a_n(n)$ in this approach, is actually equal to the last nonzero element of the vector $v^{(n)}$ which is defined in in my ["domino matrix"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614032/318073)  approach. It appears that the $n$ "domino coefficients" (in this answer) are equivalent to the $2^n$ components of the "domino matrix" vectors (in the linked answer).

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** @Bartek implements this idea and calculates more new terms [in their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3616657/318073).

**Edit:** Thank you @Bartek for your comment, I made the suggested modification.

*Remark*. Alternative approach using "domino coefficients" is in my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3611434/318073).

---

**TL;DR**

We can use a vector recurrence to keep track of new domino scenarios.

First fourteen terms given by the recurrence are: ($D_{14}$ is already larger than  $10^{21}$.)

```
D(n) = 2, 5, 18, 97, 802, 10565, 228850, 8289217, 506526530, 52501381765, 9260170733266, 2784551512218145, 1429063630276963426, 1252517782851235507141,...
```

---

**Recurrence**

We define a sequence of vectors $v^{(n)}$ to count new domino scenarios, and a "domino matrix" $M$ to encode whether or not certain domino scenarios are possible. At the $n$*th* step, it is sufficient to observe the $v^{(n)}$ and $M$ as if they are of "dimension  $(2^{n}+1)$".

The sequence $D_n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ is then the Manhattan norm of the vector sequence:

$$ D_n=||v^{(n)}||_1$$

Where the sequence of vectors $v^{(n)}=(v^{(n)}_1,v^{(n)}_2,\dots)^T$ is given by:

$$ v^{(n+1)}=v^{(n)}M $$

Where it starts with  $v^{(1)}=(1,1,0,0,\dots)^T$ as the first term.

We will be filling the "domino matrix" $M$ with $1$'s and $0$'s to represent which binary strings can or can not be generated with the corresponding rows in the domino formation.

**The matrix $M$**

To fill in the $i$*th* row (starting at $i=0$) of matrix $M$, look at the binary representation $i_{(2)}$. To fill in the $j$*th* spot (starting at $j=0$) in the row, look at the binary representation $j_{(2)}$ (padding it with leading $0$'s if necessary). Treat $i_{(2)},j_{(2)}$ as consecutive rows in the domino triangle formation, where $0$'s represent standing dominoes and $1$'s represent fallen dominoes. If it is possible to have these rows in the domino formation, we place  $1$ in the matrix. If it is not, we place $0$ in the matrix.

For example, If $i=2$ then its binary representation is $i_{(2)}=10$. This gives the only possible $j_{(2)}$'s are: $000,010,100,110$ because the rightmost domino can never fall in such case. This translates from binary to decimal as $j=0,2,4,6$. This gives that the $i=2$ row starts as $(1,0,1,0,1,0,1)$. The remainder of the row is filled with $0$'s up to the corresponding dimension.

I will give the example of $M$ when $n=4$: (The matrix is then $(2^4+1)\times(2^4+1)$)

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc}
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . \\
 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & . \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . \\
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & . & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & . & 1 \\
 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & . & . & . & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 & . & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Where individual dots "$.$"s represent zeroes "$0$"s, for visibility.

Returning back to the recursion, this indeed gives $D_n=2,5,18,97\dots$ as expected.

To compute first $n$ terms, we need first $(2^{n}+1)$ rows of the matrix $M$.

Despite its size, the matrix can be generated fast once you notice its fractal structure.

**Visualization - The fractal structure**

We can treat $0$'s and $1$'s in the matrix $M$ as black and white pixels.

Then, here is the image of a $(2^{10}+1)\times (2^{10}+1)$ case ($n=10$) of matrix $M$:

[image]

Comment: If you add column zero to $M$ consisting entirely of ones and change starting vector to $v_0=(1,1,0,0,\dots)$ then you obtain a much simpler formula for $D_n$ - that it is just the Manhattan norm of $v_n$. And also the fractal structure of your matrix becomes easier to describe. And btw the next term in the sequence is $1252517782851235507141$.

Answer (score 2):

I've computed the first $n=22$ domino coefficients based on ideas from Vepir. The algorithm has time complexity $O(4^n)$ and space complexity $O(2^n)$ (computation for $n=22$ took me around $5$ hours), because we don't store the matrix $M$ and compute its values whenever needed (the check is performed in the if statement, it has a simple form thanks to implementing bitwise operations). The code is in C++ and I am using boost to be able to use bigger data types rather than just $64$ bit long int (in fact, $256$ bits is the smallest size that can be used to compute the first $22$ coefficients and even it will run out soon - $D_{22} \approx 1.04159*10^{53}$ so the sequence indeed grows rapidly).

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const int n = 22;
    std::vector<boost::multiprecision::int256_t> v(1 << n), w = v;
    v[0] = 1;
    v[1] = 1;
    std::cout << "0: " << 1 << "\n1: " << 2 << "\n";
    for (int k = 2; k <= n; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1 << k; j++) {
            w[j] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1 << (k - 1); i++)
                if (!(j & ~i & ~(i << 1)))
                    w[j] += v[i];
        }
        boost::multiprecision::int256_t s = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 1 << k; j++) {
            v[j] = w[j];
            s += v[j];
        }
        std::cout << k << ": " << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting coefficients are:  
$D_{0\;} = 1$ 
$D_{1\;} = 2$ 
$D_{2\;} = 5$ 
$D_{3\;} = 18$ 
$D_{4\;} = 97$ 
$D_{5\;} = 802$ 
$D_{6\;} = 10565$ 
$D_{7\;} = 228850$ 
$D_{8\;} = 8289217$ 
$D_{9\;} = 506526530$ 
$D_{10 } = 52501381765$ 
$D_{11 } = 9260170733266$ 
$D_{12 } = 2784551512218145$ 
$D_{13 } = 1429063630276963426$ 
$D_{14 } = 1252517782851235507141$ 
$D_{15 } = 1875484239084442842046130$ 
$D_{16 } = 4798818821638537354534159233$ 
$D_{17 } = 20984654018757393270224583817858$ 
$D_{18 } = 156836820191186149182649796402611461$ 
$D_{19 } = 2003511561206789377122778581243926768018$ 
$D_{20 } = 43746600983206157305472349537031148375171041$ 
$D_{21 } = 1632720578386908900755016228846582339781524154786$ 
$D_{22 } = 104159355027420388820987121345303301272029996166458949$ 
$D_{23 } = 11358102129403917231432165494822142898736362479589146061682$ 
$D_{24 } = 2117071962387596476689143406365411645227548761608194942194112321$ 
$D_{25 } = 674510308152303132671249373016113929650762465949837199637457187249602$ 
$D_{26 } = 367337379241994889203376240956745359336562483947308610993230043730270521221$

The logarithm of $D_n$ seems to be growing quadratically (which can even be seen looking at the shape of the above list). We have approximately:
$$D_n \approx 2^{0.386712 n^2 - 0.667456 n + 3.63662} = \exp(0.268048 n^2 - 0.462645 n + 2.52072)$$
But I don't know how accurate this approximation is nor what the real coefficients could be. And it also doesn't tell much about the potential recursive formula - it still seems to be out of reach. 
 
This problem is a special case of the more general one - given directed graph $G$, how many ways there are to assign numbers $0$ and $1$ to its vertices such that the arrows always point in the nondecreasing direction (i.e. not from $1$ to $0$)? We can without loss of generality assume the graph is connected (otherwise the answer is just a product of the answers for the components) and that it is acyclic (the cycle implies that all its have to have the same number, thus we can collapse them into one vertex). There is an easy algorithm for answering this problem in case of a directed tree (just the recursion from the leaves up) but with vertices interacting in a more complex way, such as in this problem, it seems hard if not impossible, to come up with a fast algorithm, especially taking into account, how fast these coefficients grow (though, for example, the formula for perfect binary trees of depth $n$ grows even faster and has a simple recursion $B_{n+1}=B_n^2+1$ with $B_0=1$).

**EDIT** 
The first $5$ vectors $v_i$ generating these $D_i$ are (trailing zeros omitted): 
$v_0=(0,1)$ 
$v_1=(1,1)$ 
$v_2=(2, 1, 1, 1)$ 
$v_3=(5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1)$ 
$v_4=(18, 6, 11, 6, 11, 4, 9, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, 2)$ 
$v_5=(97, 28, 56, 28, 65, 20, 48, 20, 56, 16, 33, 16, 48, 14, 31, 14, 28, 8, 16, 8, 20, 6, 14, 6, 28, 8, 16, 8, 20, 6, 14, 6)$ 
We can find interpretation of every coefficient in this vector based on the fractal properties of $M$ - for example the first element of vector $v$ is just the sum of all elements of the previous vector (and thus it's just $D_{n-1}$. The second element is the sum of every element on the odd position (if we count positions from the left starting at $0$) and the third is the sum in every position not divisible by $4$. However, as we go further the patterns get more complex, but by analyzing them one can maybe obtain faster algorithm (for example instead of summing $\frac{3}{4}$ of the elements of the previous vector to get the third element one can just subtract from the previously computed first element the sum of the $\frac{1}{4}$ elements with indices divisible by $4$, though this enhancement can yield at most twice the speed). 
 
**EDIT 2** 
I was able to compute more terms of the sequence (up to $26$ instead of $22$) by utilizing the following algorithm:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int k = 0, n = 26;
    std::vector<boost::multiprecision::int256_t> v(1 << n - 2, 1), a(n + 1, 1);
    for (int i = 2; i < a.size(); i++)
        a[i] = 3 * a[i - 1] + 2 * a[i - 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        for (int j = i | (i << 1); j; j >>= 1) {
            k += j & 1;
            if (!(j & 1 && j - 1)){
                v[i] *= a[k + 1];
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    for (int i = n - 3; i > 0; i--) {
        std::vector<boost::multiprecision::int256_t> w(1 << i, 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < 1 << i; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 1 << i + 1; k++)
                if (!(~(j | j << 1) & k))
                    w[j] += v[k];
        v = w;
        std::cout << n - i + 1 << " " << v[1] + 1 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which can be easily parallelized speeding up the process even more. The way of computing the numbers is also different. Let $D(s,n)$ denote the valid domino configuration with binary string $s$ at the top and having $n$ layers - the initial problem is to evaluate $D('0',n)+D('1',n)=D('1',n)+1$. To obtain $D(s,n)$ we note that for $n=1$ they all equal one and for bigger $n$ we can consider all strings $s'$ directly below $n$, recursively compute all values $D(s',n-1)$ and sum them. The asymptotic complexity is the same but we can speed up the program by starting from $D(s,2)$ which is equal to $2$ to the power of the number of ones in $s$, or (as in the above algorithm) from $D(s,3)$ by noting that the number $D(s_k,3)$ where $s_k$ is the string consisting of $k$ ones is equal to OEIS A007483 which has a simple recursion and that for all other $s$ it's just the product of these numbers for each consecutive block of ones in $s$. $a_k=D(s_k,4)$, $b_k=D(s_k,5)$ and $c_k=(s_k,6)$ also have their recurrences:
$$a_{k+3}=4a_{k+2}+12a_{k+1}+8a_k$$
$$b_{k+5}=5b_{k+4}+48b_{k+3}+108b_{k+2}+64b_{k+1}-32b_k$$
$$c_{k+8}=6c_{k+7}+164c_{k+6}+896c_{k+5}+1584c_{k+4}-992c_{k+3}-3328c_{k+2}+3584c_{k+1}-1024c_k$$
With $a_0=b_0=c_0=1$, $a_1=18=D_3$, $a_2=96=D_4-1$, $b_1=97=D_4$, $b_2=801=D_5-1$, $b_3=8961$, $b_4=93697$, $c_1=802=D_5$, $c_2=10564=D_6-1$, $c_3=207720$, $c_4=3692192$, $c_5=66924256$, $c_6=1209149120$, $c_7=21854550528$. For $D(s_k,7)$ I haven't found such a series - either it doesn't exist or (more probably) there are not enough terms to detect it. Also I haven't found a way of computing $D(s,n)$ for any $n \ge 4$ for all strings $s$, that's why the algorithm makes use of only $D(s,3)$ - if one is able to compute them directly one can obtain bigger terms of the sequence. I just want to mention that $D_{26} \approx 2^{247.7}$ is the biggest term below $2^{255}$ so one will have to use bigger integer types when attempting to go higher.

Comment: Indeed, it was just a persistent coincidence ($7$ in a row). I've deleted this part of my answer, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Notice that the last element of the vector is actually $$\alpha_n(n)=1,1,1,2,6,32,288,4448,\dots$$ where $\alpha_n(k)$ is defined in my [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3611434/318073).

Comment: Indeed, the case of a directed tree is straightforward: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514829/number-of-ways-to-remove-nodes-from-a-graph-with-certain-restrictions/3427221#3427221

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  We want to find the number of 2-colorings of the triangular grid $i\in\{1,\dots,n\},\ j\in\{1,\dots,i\}$ that have none of the following properties:

- cell $(i,1)$ is black and cell $(i+1,1)$ is white
- cell $(i,i)$ is black and cell $(i+1,i+1)$ is white
- cells $(i,j)$ and $(i,j+1)$ are black and cell $(i+1,j+1)$ is white

The inclusion-exclusion expressions for small $n$ are as follows.
\begin{align}
n=1:&\quad 2^1 = \color{red}{2}\\
n=2:&\quad 2^3 - 2\cdot 2^1 + 2^0 = 8 - 4 + 1 = \color{red}{5}\\
n=3:&\quad 2^6 - (4\cdot 2^4 + 2^3) + (2^3 + 5\cdot 2^2) - 2^1 = 64 - 72 + 28 - 2 = \color{red}{18}\\
n=4:&\quad 2^{10} - (6\cdot2^8 + 3\cdot2^7) + (2^7 + 14\cdot2^6 + 11\cdot2^5) \\
&- (3\cdot2^5 + 18\cdot2^4 + 9\cdot2^3) + (4\cdot2^3 + 13\cdot2^2) - 6\cdot2^1+ 2^0 \\
&= 1024 - 1920 + 1376 - 456 + 84 - 12 + 1 = \color{red}{97}
\end{align}
For general $n$, the first three terms (up through two properties) are easy, but it gets messy after that.